# How can i add keypress on a div and actually move the div right

Tags: javascript, html, css

On keypress 39 (right arrow) move a simple div right. Like when i press the right arrow on my keyboard the div have to move right.like a game

Comment: Here's a *very* basic implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/8hv2dyf4/

Comment: And here's the real-time version: https://jsfiddle.net/8hv2dyf4/1/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
document.querySelector('#myDiv').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.key === 39) {
      e.target.style.marginLeft = '10px';
  }
})
```

Note that I didn't check the code if it works, please edit the style as you wish.